# не получается переключать streams внутри канала ActionCable при переходе по страницам

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

не переключаются потоки в канале при переходе по страницам…
в чем суть - при подключении на канал ответов происходит подключение потока с question_id

```
#answers.coffee
    $ ->
      App.answers_subscribe = App.cable.subscriptions.create 'AnswersChannel',
        connected: ->
          console.log 'Подключено к AnswersChannel'
          question_id = $('.question').data('id')
          if question_id
            @perform 'follow', id: question_id
            console.log 'follow'
          else
            @perform 'unfollow'

#answers_channel.rb
class AnswersChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def follow(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_from "answer_#{data['id']}"
  end

  def unfollow
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

при переходе между страницами не происходит unfollow, не происходит смены потока. только при принудительном F5. то есть, если пользователь обновил страницу на questions#index, то ни из одного show он потом никаких сообщений по кабелю не получит… или же, если обновился в каком-то конкретном questions#show, то подключился к потоку answers_#{question_id} и все, переподключения не происходит.
вешал я создание подписки на turbolinks:load, результатов нет.
делал App.cable.subscriptions.remove после каждой загрузки страницы, после него запускал create - работает. через раз, правда. но, получается, что я цмыкаю весь канал каждый раз, а не подписку на поток внутри канала.

из модели успешно вещаю в поток, каждый раз в актуальный. но переключиться в эот поток не могу…

читал ресурсы, смотрел видео, много думал - толку ноль. кто сталкивался - подскажите, что не так…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос снят. проблема была в турболинках. решение в том, чтобы повесить на turbolinks:load функцию, в которой происходило бы переключение между потоками или отключение от таковых:

```
  App.answers_subscribe = App.cable.subscriptions.create 'AnswersChannel',
    connected: ->
      subscribe_to_stream()

    received: (info) ->
      little_controller(info)

subscribe_to_stream = ->
  question_id = $('.question').data('id')

  if question_id
     App.answers_subscribe.perform 'follow', id: question_id
  else
     App.answers_subscribe.perform 'unfollow'
```